# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll when trying to change the image of a picture box

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to change the image of a picturebox in c#. I tried to use:

```
    picturebox.Load(path_to_image)
```

but it throws this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". I also tried to use :

```
    picturebox.Image = Image.FromFile(path_to_file);
```

but i get the same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: Look at the details of the exception. There's probably an InnerException

Comment: Wow.. thank you! It seems that you cannot use an image for two things at the same time. I am gonna remember that :) .